# Is phosphorus trichloride really a stronger Lewis acid than antimony pentafluoride?

Tags: acid-base, erratum

The following was a question from the ETS Chem GRE guide and apparently this was an actual question on an exam a few decades ago. Unfortunately, no explanation for the answer was given, and I couldn't find anything more helpful on the internet.

> Which of the following molecules is the strongest Lewis acid?
>   (a) $\ce{NF3}$
>   (b) $\ce{SbF5}$
>   (c) $\ce{NaCl}$
>   (d) $\ce{PCl3}$
>   (e) $\ce{SnCl2}$

The correct answer is supposed to be (d), which I find very surprising.  I thought it should be (b), since I know that $\ce{SbF5}$ has an empty orbital that can facilitate electron donation.  I also know it is a strong Lewis acid.

What orbital on $\ce{PCl3}$ is empty and why would $\ce{PCl3}$ be stronger than $\ce{SbF5}$?

Comment: It may be strongest base, definitely not strongest acid.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/41556/44877

Comment: Such a question is really quite interesting... Typically, we would consider electron-deficient Group 3 compounds, e.g. AlCl3, BCl3 etc. as Lewis acids and would usually consider these Group 15 compounds to be Lewis bases. Considering acidity of these compounds is rather weird...