# PF3 as a source of fluoride for substitution in alcohols

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

It is known that $\ce{PX3 (X= Cl, Br, I)}$ and $\ce{PX5 (X= Cl, Br)}$ are used to make halogen derivatives of hydrocarbons from alcohols. My question is why there's no information about using $\ce{PF3}$? At least I couldn't find any, so I assume $\ce{PF3}$ is not used for that.

A wild guess that phosphorus holds fluorine atoms tight, and no "free" fluorides are present for the last steps of the reaction to complete.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41556/why-cant-pf3-be-used-as-a-lewis-acid-catalyst-in-electrophilic-substitution-of

Comment: Yeap, I've seen that, but is this case different?

Comment: I think it's quite similar. In halogenation these halides first act as Lewis acids.

Comment: Also a good question is whether or not fluoride is a good enough nucleophile.